# not having equal height in items for carousel with image and content

Tags: reactjs, carousel

I have a carousel using material-tailwind, with equal img sizes in a container and different content which is making to have empty spaces in other carousel items [img showing extra height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grrru.jpg) [image showing the biggest content in carousal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHRrc.jpg)

I have tried using height: 100vh and other height properties, it solves the problem, but I get a lagging scroll, as I scroll it stops and start scrolling

> [www.thecuriousdev.co.in](http://www.thecuriousdev.co.in)

```
 return (
    <Carousel className="bg-[#001129]">
      {projectsData.map((project) => (
        <div className="px-4" key={project.id}>
          <h1 className="text-center text-4xl text-teal-600 my-5">
            &lt; PROJECTS &gt;
          </h1>
          <motion.div
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.95 }}
            initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 50 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 1.0 }}
          >
            <div className="screen">
              <img
                src={project.image}
                alt={project.title}
                className="w-full h-96 object-cover"
                loading="eager"
              />
            </div>
          </motion.div>
          <div className="flex place-content-center">
            <motion.div
              initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 50 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
              transition={{ duration: 1.8 }}
              className="text-justify"
              style={{ width: "75%", maxWidth: "50rem" }}
            >
              <div className="flex flex-col">
                <a
                  href={project.projectLink}
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  className="flex justify-center py-4 md:py-8 font-bold"
                >
                  <span className="text-3xl md:text-3xl text-[#8d286f] first-letter:text-6xl hover:underline">
                    {project.title}
                  </span>
                </a>
                <hr className="p-6"></hr>
                <div className="text-lg text-white text-justify">
                  <span className="block mb-12 mt-4 text-3xl font-bold first-letter:text-[#8d286f] underline">
                    Introduction:
                  </span>
                  <span className="block first-letter:text-4xl first-letter:font-bold first-letter:mr-2 first-letter:float-left first-letter:text-[#8d286f]">
                    {project.description}
                  </span>
                  <hr className="p-6 mt-12"></hr>
                  {project.futureDevelopment && (
                    <span className="block mt-4 mb-12 text-3xl font-bold first-letter:text-[#8d286f] underline">
                      Future Development:
                    </span>
                  )}
                  {project.futureDevelopment && (
                    <>
                      <span className="block mb-12 first-letter:text-4xl first-letter:font-bold first-letter:mr-2 first-letter:float-left first-letter:text-[#8d286f]">
                        {project.futureDevelopment}
                      </span>
                      <hr className="p-6"></hr>
                    </>
                  )}
                  <span className="block mt-4 mb-12 text-3xl font-bold first-letter:text-[#8d286f] underline text-left">
                    Technologies &amp; API's:
                  </span>
                  <span className="block mb-12 text-left">
                    {project.skills}
                  </span>
                  <hr className="p-6"></hr>
                </div>
                <div className="flex lg:flex-row flex-col mb-32">
                  <a
                    href={project.projectLink}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    className="bg-[#8d286f] text-white px-4 my-4 flex items-center py-2 rounded-md hover:bg-black mr-2 text-sm"
                  >
                    Live Site
                    <svg
                      className="h- w-5 mx-2"
                      fill="currentColor"
                      style={{ color: "#fffff" }}
                      viewBox="0 0 256 256"
                    >
                      <rect width="256" height="256" fill="none"></rect>
                      <circle
                        cx="128"
                        cy="128"
                        r="96"
                        fill="none"
                        stroke="#fff"
                        strokeMiterlimit="10"
                        strokeWidth="16"
                      ></circle>
                      <line
                        x1="37.467"
                        x2="218.532"
                        y1="96"
                        y2="96"
                        fill="none"
                        stroke="#fff"
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round"
                        strokeWidth="16"
                      ></line>
                      <line
                        x1="37.471"
                        x2="218.534"
                        y1="160"
                        y2="160"
                        fill="none"
                        stroke="#fff"
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round"
                        strokeWidth="16"
                      ></line>
                      <ellipse
                        cx="128"
                        cy="128"
                        fill="none"
                        stroke="#fff"
                        strokeMiterlimit="10"
                        strokeWidth="16"
                        rx="40"
                        ry="93.423"
                      ></ellipse>
                    </svg>
                  </a>
                  <a
                    href={project.repoLink}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    className="bg-teal-600 text-white px-4 my-4 flex items-center py-2 rounded-md hover:bg-black mr-2 text-sm"
                  >
                    View Code
                    <svg
                      className="h- w-5 mx-2"
                      fill="currentColor"
                      style={{ color: "#fffff" }}
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    >
                      <path d="M12 0c-6.626 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.302 3.438 9.8 8.207 11.387.599.111.793-.261.793-.577v-2.234c-3.338.726-4.033-1.416-4.033-1.416-.546-1.387-1.333-1.756-1.333-1.756-1.089-.745.083-.729.083-.729 1.205.084 1.839 1.237 1.839 1.237 1.07 1.834 2.807 1.304 3.492.997.107-.775.418-1.305.762-1.604-2.665-.305-5.467-1.334-5.467-5.931 0-1.311.469-2.381 1.236-3.221-.124-.303-.535-1.524.117-3.176 0 0 1.008-.322 3.301 1.23.957-.266 1.983-.399 3.003-.404 1.02.005 2.047.138 3.006.404 2.291-1.552 3.297-1.23 3.297-1.23.653 1.653.242 2.874.118 3.176.77.84 1.235 1.911 1.235 3.221 0 4.609-2.807 5.624-5.479 5.921.43.372.823 1.102.823 2.222v3.293c0 .319.192.694.801.576 4.765-1.589 8.199-6.086 8.199-11.386 0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12z" />
                    </svg>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </motion.div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Carousel>
  );
}
```